# Catching memory loss in Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory-management

It seems to me that my app eats too much memory. Is there a way to control memory usage in Flash? Amount of Movie Clips in memory? Amount of text fields?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Alcon Debugger](http://blog.hexagonstar.com/downloads/alcon/)

Comment: looks great! thank you! is it possible to get the amount of movie clips via alcon?

Answer (score 2):

Check [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/)

Answer (score 1):

check out http://jpauclair.net/flashpreloadprofiler/ and read http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3